# AndroidStuidio: Touch on EditText not enabled

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText not enabled in my activity.
I want to detect the touch on the text to open a dialog, but I can't detect the touch with OnTouchListener().
How could I do with leaving edittext disabled?

Comment: you can use setOnClickListener.

Comment: You can add an underlay view that has the same size and position as the edit text. Then set click event to the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing the following steps:

Make the EditText enabled:

```
android:enabled="true"
```

Make the EditText not clickable:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Make the appearance look like disabled:

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

Now you can use ***OnTouchListener()*** with the appearance and functionality of the disabled view

Note: ***OnClickListener()*** will not work

If you want toggle this in code, you can do like this in Kotlin:

```
//making disabled
editText.alpha = 0.5f
editText.isClickable = false

//making enabled
editText.alpha = 1f
editText.isClickable = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setOnClickListener

Designing XML

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

Coding

```
edt.setClickable(false);
edt.setFocusable(false);
```